# Not able to connect to mysql in java

Tags: java, mysql

I was trying to connect to `MySQL` using `JAVA` I used the same code to connect the database in my localhost. Now I tried to use it in my system to update the remote database. Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;
class mysqlConnect { 

public static void main (String[] args) { 
    try { 
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://dibyaranjan.net76.net/a3932573_product";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"a3932573_dibya","*****"); 
        Statement st = conn.createStatement(); 
        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO emp_oracle " + "VALUES (1001, 'Dibya', 'AAA')"); 
        conn.close(); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    } 

}
}
```

I get this error message:
**null,  message from server: "Host '49.204.14.98' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"**.

The ip is my public ip.

Comment: Does your database allow foreign connections? (e.g. not from localhost)

Comment: I have tried in PHP. I could able to connect from my localhost to that server.

Comment: Is the username/password combo correct?

Comment: Yes very much. These values are correct

Comment: Do you have access to the mysql command prompt?

Comment: try this in command prompt, `mysql -h dibyaranjan.net76.net -u a3932573_dibya -p ` and type in password when prompted. what happens?

Comment: @SubinS: Getting the same error message host is not allowed.

Comment: ok that means user dont have permission, may be your provider allows only local connections, check with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your host is configured incorrectly in the `mysql.user` table.

Open `PHPMyAdmin` and find your record in the `mysql.user` table. `ALTER` the table so that instead of `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or any other IP, the hostname reflects your actual IP (or `%` if you wish to allow connections from every IP. Note however that most shared hosts do not allow this sort of configuration.

For more reference: http://blog.wassupy.com/2011/02/host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this.html

Answer (score 1):

Error is clear. You cant connect to the remote mysql server from your machine. `a3932573_dibya` this user is not  having permission to connect from this IP.

When you create a user in mysql, we can also specify which all IP's this user will connect from. If you want to allow all IPs you should give host as `%`

Comment: How can I set these permission by the way I am using a free hosting so I couldn't have all the privileges.

Comment: you should check with hosting company to see if your user is allowed to connect form `%` not only from `localhost`

Comment: Where can see if the user is allowed to connect from `%` and how can I change it to accept my user name. Please suggest me I don't have much experience in hosting

Comment: if you are able to connect to your mysql, may be by logging into the server via ssh . Then there is a database called `mysql` and a table in it called `user` . you will need to update host column with `%`